# Creating template based iwidgets in Dojo.?

Tags: widget, rad, dojo

I am learning Dojo 
And trying to create a  iWidget on WebShere Application server.

I first tried to create `Helloworld` widget.
Which got deployed.

Now i want to add template.

I create a `LoginCmis.html` in Template folder this template is gui for asking Username and password.

**in `CustomerInteraction.js` i have created a template String . How to add this on `onLoad`.**

```
 <div class = LoginCmis>
        <div dojotype="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" id="BorderContainer"
        design="headline" style="height: 250px; width: 400px" align="center">

            <div preload="true" dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" 
                region="top">Login CMIS
            </div>
            <div preload="true" dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="centre">

                <table class="form">
                    <tr>
                        <td>UserName</td>
                        <td><input type="text" dojotype="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"
                            name="username" required="true" maxLength=64 trim="true"
                            style="width: 200px; text-align: left" 
                            dojoattachpoint="username"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password</td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="password" value=""
                            dojotype="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" 
                            style="width: 200px; text-align: left"
                            dojoattachpoint="password"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

in my `CustomerInteraction.xml` (this was for Hello world do i have to make any changes here) fot the content

```
<iw:content mode="view">
        <![CDATA[
              <div id ="helloWorld" > Hello World ! </div>
       ]]>
 </iw:content>
```

In `customerInteraction.js`

```
    dojo.provide("helloWorldScope");
    dojo.require("dijit._Widget");
    dojo.require("dijit._Templated");
    dojo.declare("",[ dijit._Widget, dijit._Templated ],{

        templateString : dojo["cache"]("iWidget/widgets/CustomerInteraction", "Template/LoginCmis.html");


        msg1: "Hello World Class Loaded",
        msg2: "Hello World, again",


    onLoad:function() {
            alert(this.msg1);
        }
});
```

**What are the change i have to make to view this template??**

the folder design look this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this mixin `_WidgetsInTemplateMixin` to youre declaration.

A widget has no default `onLoad` function to call / bind. It will however as final stage of constructing itself, call `startup`

Make sure dojo knows where to look for youre module and make a div with type so that dojo.parser can reckognize it as a widget.

#### CustomerInteraction.xml:

```
 <script>
      dojo.registerModulePath("iWidgets", "/iWidget");
      dojo.require("iWidget.widgets.customerInteraction");
 </script>
 <div dojoType="iWidget.widgets.customerInteraction"></div> ... </body>
```

#### WebContent/iWidget/widgets/customerInteraction.js

```
dojo.declare("iWidget.widgets.customerInteraction",[ dijit._Widget, dijit._Templated, dijit._WidgetsInTemplateMixin ],{
     ....
     buildRendering: function() {
          // pre-parser point in flow of construction
          // add you code here
          this.inherited(arguments);
     },
     startup: function() {
          // 'post create' point in flow of construction
          // add you code here
          this.inherited(arguments);
     }
});
```

Comment: Sir, I am very new to dojo and i just learning with the examples given on the websites.I my project  for html page LoginCmis.html there is no body or head script.It just what i have mentioned in the above code. About onLoad : isnt onLoad is like public static void main in Java.

Comment: then simply put it in your cdata section. onLoad in terms of dojo means when a script has *finished* loaded or a page has loaded. The global body-onload-and-dojo-parser-done is called via `dojo.addOnLoad(function() {});`. The module's `main(void)` method is called `constructor`, since we're abstracting the module into classLike.

Comment: :Sir do you have any easy sample code for adding template or any link where i can learn it.cause i think i am no able to locate the HTML properly in .js

Comment: this site is really not meant for tutoring imo.. have a look at some of the .js files under `dojotoolkit/dojox/widget`, for instance dojox.image.Badge is pretty simple. Your buzzwords for searches are dijit templating widgetsintemplate - sitepen has some good startingpoints